# Trouble Using GoJS initialAutoscale Diagram Property - How Does it Work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gojs

I am having trouble getting my GoJS Diagram to scale properly initially by setting the initialAutoScale property on the Diagram object as so:

```
myDiagram.initialAutoScale = go.Diagram.Uniform;
```

however, I AM able to set the fixed auto scale value like this, although it is not the behavior I want (does not allow ctrl-scroll zoom after initialization):

```
myDiagram.autoScale = go.Diagram.Uniform;
```

Admittedly, I am controlling and managing the GoJs Diagram from an Angular controller, which I understand is not the recommended way to use GoJS with Angular. That said, I am working with a short schedule on a web application that is much bigger than the piece I am currently working on and it is the best for the project if I CAN make it work within the controller construct.

Given that, I would love a recommendation for a fix, but also would very much appreciate any feedback regarding why autoScale might've worked while initialAutoScale doesn't, how initialAutoScale works and why in particular it might be angry with my Angular controller implementation, why else initialAutoScale wouldn't be happy, or any other ideas for a workaround.

I am happy to post more code as it is helpful. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Diagram.initialAutoScale** determines the scale of the diagram after the **Diagram.model** has been replaced.  So if you have set `initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform`, for example, then after you have replaced the **Diagram.model** with a new Model, the **Diagram.scale** will eventually be set so that the whole **Diagram.documentBounds** can be seen in the viewport.

If you do not replace the diagram's model, this property has no effect.

Setting **Diagram.autoScale** to `go.Diagram.Uniform` basically results in a call to **Diagram.zoomToFit** whenever there is a change to the document bounds or the viewport size or scale or scrollbar visibility or any other state which affects what is shown and where.

See http://gojs.net/latest/intro/initialView.html for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helps to see the differences between the two put succinctly and next to one another. I think I have a better idea how to use these properties to get my desired behavior now.